# App crashing through APK, but working locally

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, gradle

I have been assigned to download an android app from a repository and, after a few visual changes, make an app bundle and upload it to Google Play. I have been able to use it locally just fine, both on Android Studio's emulator and on a physical device.

However, when I go to `Build > Generate signed App Bundle/APK` and do it, and then use bundletools to install it in the device I'm using to test, the app continually crashes when starting to load.

I have also successfully upload a (non-working) version to Google Play and this is the error it throws:

```
at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.jniLoadScriptFromAssets (Native Method)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.loadScriptFromAssets (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:218)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSBundleLoader$1.loadScript (JSBundleLoader.java:31)
  at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle (CatalystInstanceImpl.java:247)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext (ReactInstanceManager.java:1152)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$900 (ReactInstanceManager.java:123)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run (ReactInstanceManager.java:943)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

I've tried multiple things, including editing the build.gradle, tamper with the signature, etc.

This is my current build.gradle:

````
import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.storev2.bexfy"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 212
        versionName "2.1.2"

        ndk {
            ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'
        }
        renderscriptTargetApi 21
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("./***")
            keyAlias "***"
            storePassword "***"
            keyPassword "***"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk true  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'arm64-v8a', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
   }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-camera')
    implementation project(":rncamerakit")
    implementation project(':react-native-fast-image')
    implementation project(':@react-native-community_async-storage')
    implementation project(':react-native-video')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    implementation project(':react-native-orientation')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    // implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook:react:0.12.2.4'// From node_modules
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an issue with your version of Gradle. Try upgrading to version 5.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0'
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

Please look at this link and see the full answer of resolving your issue:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24861

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23891540)

Comment: Thanks Valentino. New to this. Edited my response.